# In Minecraft, what is the most space-efficient way to construct AND and OR Redstone gates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

With Redstone you can create wiring and circuitry.  Using this, it is possible to create complex devices and even "programs".  Unfortunately, the size of such projects usually tends to be *massive* in the in-game world and difficult to navigate.  In order to reduce the size of the project, does anyone know the most space-efficient construction of the AND and OR logic gates?

Comment: Get the developer to add semiconductors to the game?  Or vacuum tubes?

Comment: Depends on your definition of space. You can have gates which are perfectly flat, or ones that take up just a single row horizontally. Depends on how you're using them in your machine. It's often better to just understand them so you can "custom make" gates in the shape you need.

Comment: Of course, if you're willing to use mods, Redpower 2 condenses the basic gates into single blocks. It's part of both the Technic Pack and Tekkit, so it's quite easy to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways of constructing the gates you are interested in. I would trust what's already well documented on the Minecraft Wiki:

- [AND Gates](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Logic_circuit#AND_Gate)
- [OR Gates](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Logic_circuit#OR_Gate)

From the wiki page there are several considerations you have to keep in mind in making the decision of which design you go with.

Barring changes to Minecraft I'm not sure you have many other alternatives (though I'm sure there's a mod out there with more compact gate support.)

Comment: at the mod support check out [redpower](http://www.eloraam.com/) (it's not updated to 1.4.4 yet though)